# Multivariate density of the form $\exp(-\|x\|_r^s)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request

Is there a general name for densities of the following form?
$$
p(x) \propto \exp(-\|x\|_r^s), \quad r \in [1, \infty],  s \in [1, \infty).
$$
For $r=s=2$, it is a product of Gaussians, and for $r=s=1$, it is a product of Laplace distributions.

I'm particularly interested in $r = \infty, s = 1$, but the general case above is interesting. It is not even clear to me that this is always a density (i.e., normalizable).

Answer (score 1):

I can at least tell you that its always a density for your range of indices.  By equivalence of norms, one has $$ \exp(-\|x\|_r^s) \le \exp(-C^s_{r,d}\|x\|^s_1 ) \le \exp(-C^s_{r,d}\|x\|_1 )$$
which shows that it has a finite integral, which is of course the normalising constant.

Comment: Lol oops, yes. As a comment for those unfamiliar: let $\mu, \nu$ be two norms on $\mathbb{R}^d$. There exist $c:= c_d(\mu, \nu), C:=C_d(\mu, \nu)$ such that $$c\mu(x) \leq \nu(x) \leq C \mu(x) \quad \text{for all}~x\in \mathbb{R}^d.$$ Combine this with monotonicity of $\exp(\cdot)$ and use $\mu = \|\cdot\|_r, \nu =\|\cdot\|_1$ for the result above.

Comment: There's a minor typo, should be $1+\|x\|_1 $ in the end of the line

Comment: Sorry, where is the typo? I don't see a natural place to replace $\|x\|_1$ with $\|x\|_1 +1$.

Comment: @DrewBrady there is a typo in my correction, its easier to only apply the above bound for $x$ large, since $x$ small doesn't present any issues (sorry!)